# Electron app throw version Module version mismatch error. Expected 49, got 48

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I try running electron app, after updating node to `6.3.0`.

I update all dependencies to latest and when i try running the app, it throw following error,

```
/Volumes/Shankar_Drive/Work/git/safe_launcher/testApp/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
        ^

Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 49, got 48.
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:167:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:167:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at bindings (/Volumes/Shankar_Drive/Work/git/safe_launcher/testApp/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
```

I tried `npm cache clean && npm install` and also removing `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` no use in that.

I even tried `electron-rebuild` on specific modules say ('ffi' and 'ref'), but no use
Environment I run these:

`node 6.3.0`

`npm 3.8.6`

`electron-prebuild 1.3.1`

Please someone help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I moved to building with two package.json files https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/601

Comment: This question seems like a duplicate but it's not as it can require a specialized command with Electron. See my answer and script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module version mismatch. Expected 49, got 48](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091758/module-version-mismatch-expected-49-got-48)

Answer (score 3):

I have just created a shell script to deal with this specifically for Electron. Why? Because removing node_modules doesn't always work and so many people have this problem. A simple rebuild without special flags won't necessarily work either.

This script takes the target abi version as the first argument and detects your Electron version automatically. You can optionally pass your electron version as the second argument but 99% of the time the "Expected" abi version should be enough.

Here it is: https://github.com/TomAshley303/electron-abi-fix

Simply drop it into your project directory and run: sh electron-abi-fix.sh 49

(If 49 is the expected abi version in your error). You can also pass the Electron version as a second argument but shouldn't need to.