# Module version mismatch. Expected 49, got 48

Tags: node.js, electron

I am using Electron module mdns and I am getting this error

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 49, got 48.
    at Error (native)
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:167:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:568:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:167:20)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ingsaurabh/dp/node_modules/mdns/lib/dns_sd.js:24:20)
```

Uninstalled node module and reinstalled, but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `mdns` contains a native Node module you must rebuild it to target your version of Electron, there are [a couple of ways to do this](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules/). I'd suggest using the `electron-rebuild` approach.

Answer (score 2):

npm rebuild --runtime=electron --target=1.3.4 --disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell --abi=**50**

in your case it should be **49**

Answer (score 1):

This is well-know problem when when upgrading node version. For example: you are using Node for example version 5. You add some libraries inside your project, build and run that. All your libraries will be compiled under node version 5.

And then you upgrade your node for example to version 6. And then you run some commands that using node, for example npm run test. The problem is here: you use newer node version for running libraries that compiled by older node.

Solving this is easy by 2 following commands:

```
rm -rf node_modules // force remove node_modules directory
npm install         // install again all libraries. Libraries will be compiled again with node version 6
```

So this is a general method apply for all javascript frameworks, not only `electron` ...