# Atom package pocketsphinx integration issue

Tags: atom-editor, pocketsphinx

I'm trying to integrate Pocketsphinx with Atom package, I installed all the dependencies required.

However, every time I launch the package I get the follwoing error:

```
Module version mismatch. Expected 49, got 48.
```

Here is a part of the stack trace:

```
Error: Module version mismatch. Expected 49, got 48.
at Error (native)
at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:168:20)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:583:18)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:168:20)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
at require (/Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/src/native-compile-cache.js:50:27)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/firas/github/sourcefetch/node_modules/pocketsphinx/index.js:1:99)
at Module._compile (/Applicat
```

And here is the code I'm using to import pocketsphinx after installing it using npm:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var ps = require('pocketsphinx').ps;
```

The exception is happening as soon as I reload the package.

Also, do you have any other suggestion for a library that does the job? (voice commands in atom package)

EDIT: it's not the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091758/module-version-mismatch-expected-49-got-48) because I'm using a different library and tried those solutions and I'm asking for an alternative library for voice recognition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Module version mismatch. Expected 49, got 48](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39091758/module-version-mismatch-expected-49-got-48)

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Actually I already tried that solution, and here I'm asking for an alternative way to implement voice recognition, so I don't think it is the same question, thanks.